# Refresh User Control without Refreshing the Page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, postback

I have a page and it has a button and a user control. 
I want to refresh the user control without refreshing the page.

I know I cannot do it otherwise so what I did is wrapped my user control inside the Update Panel.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add name to list" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" /><br /><br />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upShowNames" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
     <uc1:ShowNames ID="ucShowNames" runat="server" />
 </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But I still the control won't refresh.
I also tried calling the update panels. The `Update()` method by changing its UpdateMode to Conditional but that does not work either...

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: Did you try putting the button definition inside your update panel?
so have it appear in the ContentTemplate just before your uc1 control

Answer (score 4):

Please change these 2 things

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upShowNames" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">`

`<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" EventName="Click"/>`

You missed the EventName on the postback trigger, once you add that, it should work :-)

Comment: hey buddy thanks for the help but i have already mentioned that i did try with the UpdateMode= Conditional thingi...
and it did not work...

any other suggestions ??

Comment: Please, read the complete description. The main thing you have missed is EventName="Click" on the AsyncPostBackTrigger